# Read AEM DAM csv files using Python

Tags: python, adobe, aem, dam

I have a requirement to read data from a csv in AEM DAM environment. The data will then be processed using Python/Databricks and stored elsewhere. Is there an API or equivalent process to read this data using Python? I can only see Java API for AEM design and setup.

Comment: There is an OOB asset download servlet,it could help you. You can also download the CSV files with regular curl commands, if you want to process them with Python. But if you want to read the data before processing it to the Python code, then you need custom code and expose a servlet that gives you the required data. There are many entries on how to read an asset in Java. 

Asset asset =  resource.adaptTo(Asset.class);

if (asset != null) {

  AssetMetadata meta = asset.getMetadata();

....

}

Answer (score 0):

You could create a servlet that fetches the CSV from AEM DAM.
This servlet can then be accessed through Python and store file somewhere else.